# self invoking function loop vs. for loop performance and render blocking question

Tags: javascript, for-loop, self-invoking-function

I am animating an element and when it reaches the bounds of the container it will stop. I am wondering if a self invoking function loop is better in performance or a for loop is better? Are they both render blocking or not? I am intending to use requestAnimationFrame in whichever I end up using, I just want to hear other's input on which is better. Thanks.

Example of self invoking function loop:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect();
var move_me = document.getElementById('move_me').getBoundingClientRect();
var move_distance = 50;
(function loop_me(){
    move_distance += move_distance;
    if(move_me.right >= container.right){
        return null;
    }
    move_me.style.transform = 'translate3d('+move_distance+'px,0,0)';
    move_me.style.transition = '120ms linear';
    loop_me();
})();
```

vs.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect();
var move_me = document.getElementById('move_me').getBoundingClientRect();
var move_distance = 50;
for(i < elem.right; i < container.right; i++){
    move_distance += move_distance;
    if(move_me.right >= container.right){
       break;
    }
    move_me.style.transform = 'translate3d('+move_distance+'px,0,0)';
    move_me.style.transition = '120ms linear';
}
```

Comment: "*I am intending to use requestAnimationFrame*" - since that requires a callback, you cannot use a loop. And even the "self invoking function" won't invoke itself recursively, it will *re-schedule* itself for the next animation frame

Comment: I see, thank you, I will not use the requestanimationframe. I am still interested in knowing which of the two loop is better and are either of them render blocking? Because there are other animations that could possibly happen in the page while these loops are happening. BTW this is for a mobile browser that is why the render blocking thing is very important for me to know

Comment: "*I will not use the requestanimationframe*" - but you need to, how would you do an animation without it? Both snippets you've shown are synchronous, blocking code, and the browser won't render anything until they're finished executing. No difference between a loop and recursive calls in that regard.

Comment: I am using transform: translate3d to move the element while calling the loop and when it reaches the container bounds I stop the loop. It is working without the requestAnimationFrame. Just wondering which is more efficient, but I guess they're just the same

Comment: Can you post your actual code please? I doubt that works properly.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with the codes for the loops

Comment: Ah, it's the transition CSS that is causing the animation. You don't even need any loop/recursion for that - just set the target transform and you're done.